# Set "basedir" option for Pug in NestJS

Tags: node.js, pug, nestjs

I'm trying to use `pug` layouts in `NestJS`, however when extending a layout from an absolute path, `pug` requires the `basedir` option to be set.

In ExpressJS you would use `app.locals.basedir = ...`, what would be the equivalent in NestJS?

```
const server = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
server.setViewEngine('pug');
server.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, 'templates', 'views'));
await server.listen(config.server.port);
```

Using `extends /layouts/index` in a view would throw the following; `the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths`.

I'm not looking to use relative paths, since this quickly becomes very messy. E.g. `extends ../../../layouts/index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around through the documentation, NestJS uses an express under the hood, and gives you access to the underlying instance with `getHttpAdapter().getInstance()`.

Keeping that in mind, we can set the `basedir` as follows;

```
const express = server.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
express.locals.basedir = join(__dirname, 'templates');
```

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell, you can achieve the same functionality as `/layouts/index` with just using `layout/index` so long as `layout` is a folder in your `templates/views` directory.

I've [set up a git repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-pug-mvp) as a working example so you can test it out yourself and see if I need to go in more depth about anything.

**EDIT** 6/27/2019:

Thank you, I misunderstood your initial question.

With creating and express based application, you can send an `express server` to the `NestFactory` to use that server instance instead of having Nest create a plain instance for you. From here you can set up the `express server` as you normally would and get the desired functionality. I've modified the git repo to be able to test the scenario better and believe this is what you are looking for.

My `main.ts`

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication, ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { join } from 'path';

async function bootstrap() {
  // Creating and setting up the express instanced server
  const server = express();
  server.locals.basedir = join(__dirname, '..', 'views');
  // Using the express server instance in the nest factory
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('pug');
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Overall the folder set up is like so

```
src
|-app.controller.ts
|-app.module.ts
|-app.service.ts
|-main.ts
views
|-hello
  |-home.pug
|-message
  |-message.pug
|-templates
  |-layout.pug
```

And the beginning of my `home.pug` and `message.pug` files is `extends /templates/layout`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but like I indicated in the question, I’m not looking to use relative paths.

Comment: You're right! I totally misinterpreted that. See the edit for an updated answer.

Comment: Saw your edit a bit late, but you're right, however Nest will create it's own Express instance that you can access with `getHttpAdapter().getInstance()`, from there you're able to set the `locals.basedir`.

Comment: Both are viable options. Nest will create its own instance if one is not already passed to it. I saw Kamil respond to your GitHub issue with the `getHttpAdatper().getInstance()`. I think that overall is a better approach, but it is nice to know both work.