# NestJs Microservice - Which location do I read files from?

Tags: nestjs, pug-loader

Wondering if anyone can help? I am trying to learn how to use NestJS **microservices**. I have managed to succesfully get a microservice with MQTT transport setup to receive events from an API. I am trying to use [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) to merge the event information with a html template file. However pug cannot find the template file...

```
  this.logger.info(`Running from dir ${__dirname}`); // /usr/src/app/dist/apps/microservice
  const template = pug.compileFile('../templates/email.pug');
```

I have used a logger to display *__dirname* which refers to the dist directory. This has the single file main.js inside. How do I bundle and read a template pug file from nestjs microservice?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721356/set-basedir-option-for-pug-in-nestjs) has a similar question, however it is for a nestjs app.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to configure the express instance

```
  // main.ts
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
       AppModule,
  );
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');
```

Put templates folder in root with the neighborhood src folder

[image]

but you must find it not in dist folder because Typescript compiler dont copy non-typescript files to dist folder for that approach you can use copy-webpack-plugin
but i just advise you change this url( ../templates/email.pug) so that to find folder located in root not find it in dist
hope it will help you! if not please provide your file structure. 
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc

Comment: Thanks for responding @har17bar. I am using NestJS microservices (https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#getting-started) and not the usual express application as created with ```NestFactory.create``` method. For the time being I am representing the pug template as a string in memory. When I get time will investigate [pug-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-loader) in addition to your suggestion of loading the file from root. Many thanks again :)